# Why doesn't ParametricNDSolve execute the action of WhenEvent, except the first occurrence?

Tags: parametric-functions, event-detection

I'm trying to create a ParametricFunction object using ParametricNDSolve targeting a system of equations that involves WhenEvent and DiscreteVariables. For some reason I fail to discover, the resulting object does not give the same solution as NDSolve. I will use one of the examples from the reference page of [NDSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) (Applications - Electrical Systems - DC-to-DC boost converter) to present the issue:

```
system = {vo'[t] == q[t] i[t]/c - vo[t]/(r c), i'[t] == -q[t] vo[t]/l + vi/l, vo[0] == 0, i[0] == 0};
control = {q[0] == 1, WhenEvent[Mod[t, \[Tau]] == (vi/vd) \[Tau], q[t] -> 0], WhenEvent[Mod[t, \[Tau]] == 0, q[t] -> 1]};
pars = {vi -> 24, vd -> 36, r -> 22, l -> 2 10^-1, c -> 1 10^-4, \[Tau] -> 5 10^-5};
sol = NDSolve[{system, control} /. pars, {vo, i, q}, {t, 0, .2}, DiscreteVariables -> q];
```

The solution of `q[t]` is as expected:

```
Plot[q[t] /. First[sol], {t, 0, .001}]
```

[image: Solution of q[t] with NDSolve]

Using ParametricNDSolve to create a parametric solution of the same problem:

```
solPar = ParametricNDSolve[{system, control}, {vo, i, q}, {t, 0, .2}, pars[[All, 1]], DiscreteVariables -> q];
```

Plotting the solution of q[t] obtained with ParametricNDSolve:

```
Plot[q[Sequence @@ pars[[All, 1]]][t] /. solPar /. pars // Evaluate, {t, 0, .001}]
```

[image]

It seems like ParametricNDSolve executes only the very first occurrence of the action in WhenEvent, but after that `q[t]` doesn't get changed anymore. At first glance I thought of `"ParametricCaching"`, but including the option `Method -> {"ParametricCaching" -> None}` doesn't improve the situation.

**The question:**

What is the reason behind that ParametricNDSolve gives different/unexpected result for the very same problem? Any suggestion or comment is very welcome and appreciated! Thanks a lot!